# Javascript double if statement checking conditions

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am experiencing an issue with my if statement shown below:

```
    heatmapData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ob.d.length; i++) {
               if (document.getElementById("infobox").value == "10") {
                   if (ob.d[i][3] == "21/04/2016") {
                       var c = [ob.d[i][1], ob.d[i][2]];
                       var pointLL = new google.maps.LatLng(c[0], c[1]);
                       heatmapData.push(pointLL);
                   }
               }
           }
```

I am relatively new to javascript and was looking for some guidance as to why this isn't working. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactely ?

Comment: Also, post the corresponding HTML

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif I wish for both if the conditions in the if statements to be true and if so, I want to create a list called 'c' and then another called pointLL

Comment: Please, what is your issue? Why doesn't it "work"?

Comment: @SébastienTemprado the lists do not populate..

Comment: WHere is your html?

Comment: Also, what does your `ob.d` object look like?

Comment: since `document.getElementById("infobox").value` looks like it isn't going to get updated inside the loop, and because the loop looks like its going to happen in less than a second, consider moving `if (document.getElementById("infobox").value == "10")` outside the for loop

Comment: everything looks fine depending on what you want... I would maybe just move your if statements together for simplicity sake..
`if (document.getElementById("infobox").value == "10" && ob.d[i][3] == "21/04/2016) {
  ...
}`
but upon closer examination @ajax333221 makes a good point to move that out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

heatmapData isn’t declared as a variable.

There don’t seem to be any other syntax errors.

People are asking for the HTML, could you maybe set up a jsfiddle to demonstrate your problem?